# Slow TFTP File Transfer in Uboot 2020

Tags: boot-loader, u-boot, tftp

I've got a tftp server running on a virtual machine host, and I'm trying to tftp a linux kernel onto a TI AM33 processor. Both devices are connected on the same network switch. I'm noticing that TFTP is much slower on uboot 2020 compared to uboot 2013. My uboot 2013 has a transfer time of ~14 seconds, and 2020 has a transfer time of 5 minutes. Is there something in the configuration that I can change. I have set `TFTP_BLOCKSIZE` to `1464` and `TFTP_WINDOWSIZE` I've tried values between 1-16. Are there variables in the UDP stack that it would be good to check? This is a picture of wireshark for the device. I was wondering if the response time seems quick enough as well?

In wireshark I'm seeing an average response time of .00043 seconds Is that slow for TFTP?

Comment: Please provide more details on your platform, and why you're moving to only a 2020 release.  Currently am335x_evm (and the GP EVM kit) is giving me 7.8MiB/s over tftp, which feels like what it's been for nearly forever.

Comment: ```[11:58:04][envoy:~$] cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 795.64
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware        : Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```
As to why 2020, its beyond my pay grade. I'm just going to compile from source without whatever random patches I was given.

Comment: I can mark resolved for now, I'll check diffs to see if something was oddly added/omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really an answer, but when looking at wireshark I noticed a lot of dropped packets, so I ended up setting the `tftptimeout` to 1000, and `tftptimeoutcountmax` to 6000 (number of packets x 2). Which led to a much faster timout